# Spinnaker CloudDriver Pod crashing because of IAM issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

When deploying Spinnaker to EKS via hal deploy apply, Spinnaker Clouddriver pod goes to CrashLoopBackOff with the following error,

> Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AWSSecurityTokenServiceException: User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/Spinnaker-k8s-Worker-Node-Role/i-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/Spinnaker-Managed-Role

My Halyard config is like follows,

```
currentDeployment: default
deploymentConfigurations:
- name: default
  version: 1.17.6
  providers:
    appengine:
      enabled: false
      accounts: []
    aws:
      enabled: true
      accounts:
      - name: my-account
        requiredGroupMembership: []
        providerVersion: V1
        permissions: {}
        accountId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx' # my account id here
        regions:
        - name: us-east-1
        assumeRole: Spinnaker-Clouddriver-Role
        lifecycleHooks: []
      primaryAccount: my-account
      bakeryDefaults:
        baseImages: []
      defaultKeyPairTemplate: '{{name}}-keypair'
      defaultRegions:
      - name: us-east-1
      defaults:
        iamRole: BaseIAMRole
```

My `Spinnaker-Clouddriver-Role` IAM role has `PowerUserAccess` permissions at the moment and has following as the Trust Relationship

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "ec2.amazonaws.com",
          "ecs.amazonaws.com",
          "application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/Spinnaker-k8s-Worker-Node-Role"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I get this resolved?

---

The full log can be found on https://gist.github.com/agentmilindu/d9d31ee4287c87fb87e5060e0709989d#file-awssecuritytokenserviceexception-log-L3

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at an AWS IAM policy that works flawlessly.

Refer to [Armory AWS IAM set up](https://docs.armory.io/spinnaker-install-admin-guides/add-aws-account/) and [EC2 provider set up](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/providers/aws/aws-ec2/)

> ```
> {
>     "Version": "2012-10-17",
>     "Statement": [
>         {
>             "Effect": "Allow",
>             "Action": [
>                 "ec2:*",
>                 "cloudformation:*",
>                 "ecr:*"                
>             ],
>             "Resource": [
>                 "*"
>             ]
>         },
>         {
>             "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
>             "Resource": [
>                 "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/SpinnakerManagedRoleAccount1",
>                 "arn:aws:iam::101121314157:role/SpinnakerManagedRoleAccount2",
>                 "arn:aws:iam::202122232425:role/SpinnakerManagedRoleAccount3"
>             ],
>             "Effect": "Allow"
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```